# Getting error of "Fatal error: Index out of range" upon trying to configure two cells in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am getting the error of "Fatal error: Index out of range", when I configuring two cells in a tableview, ShareSomthingCell is fixed and shows only one time, but the postcell is repetitive as per the database

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1 + posts.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ShareSomethingCell") as? DetailsCellInHomeScreen {
                if currentUserImageUrl != nil {
                   cell.configCell(userImgUrl: currentUserImageUrl)
                   cell.shareBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toCreatePost), for: .touchUpInside)
                }
                return cell
            }
        }

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as? PostTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

        cell.btnComment.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.btnComment.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toComments(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        cell.favoritebutton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.favoritebutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(favupdate(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row - 1])
        return cell


        }
```

I am getting error at this line

```
cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row - 1])
```

Comment: Please show more code where you are returning `numberOfRows`.

Comment: what's in the posts list? what's in your numberOfRowsInSection and numberOfSections methods?

Comment: @Kamran added the required code,  the posts list is a feed

Comment: @DevB2F added the required code, the posts list is a feed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash happens if there is a design mistake regarding the first cell.

Don't `guard` cells, force unwrap them always. If the crash occurs there the identifier is wrong or the class is not set but this can be fixed immediately.

This code must not cause an out-of-range exception.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ShareSomethingCell" for: indexPath) as! ScoresCellInHomeScreen 
        if let imageURL = currentUserImageUrl {
           cell.configCell(userImgUrl: imageURL)
           cell.shareBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toCreatePost), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
        return cell            
    }

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell

    cell.btnComment.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.btnComment.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toComments(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    cell.favoritebutton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.favoritebutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(favupdate(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row - 1])
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `"postCell"` as first cell `(indexpath.row == 0)`, app would crash.

In above scenario, control goes to first `if` statement (`if indexPath.row == 0`) but escapes second `if` (`if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ShareSomethingCell")`)

and control eventually comes to `cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row - 1])` and as `indexpath.row == 0`, your code is trying to access `posts[-1]` which leads to crash