# How to get the error "Fatal error: Index out of range" while retrieving data from Firestore?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview

I am retrieving user data from two different collection for different cells, I am able to retrieve data but able to set the data to one cell of

```
  override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1 + posts.count
    }


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "detailscell") as! DetailsCellInHomeScreen
            if let imageURL = currentUserImageUrl {
                cell.configCell(userImgUrl: imageURL)
                cell.shareBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toCreatePost), for: .touchUpInside)
            }
            cell.set(details: details[indexPath.row])
            return cell
        }

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell

        cell.btnComment.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.btnComment.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toComments(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        cell.favoritebutton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.favoritebutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(favupdate(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row - 1])
        return cell
    }
```

getting error at this line

```
cell.set(details: details[indexPath.row])
```

Comment: can we have all the code that concerns `posts` , `details`, and  the firestore call(s) in your table view controller?

Comment: This,  `return 1 + posts.count`, and this, `posts[indexPath.row - 1]`, makes me believe you are doing something wrong somewhere else in your code or design

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting error of "Fatal error: Index out of range" upon trying to configure two cells in tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58297187/getting-error-of-fatal-error-index-out-of-range-upon-trying-to-configure-two). Please don't post your same question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is you are returning `1 + posts.count` from `numberOfRowsInSection:` method as below.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1 + posts.count
}
```

and you are not handling when your index path is reached at `posts.count`.

**Solution**

So the solution is to return *posts.count* from numberOfRowsInSection: method.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return posts.count
}
```

OR you can handle this fatal error in `cellForRow:` method.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
       .
       .
       .

        //Handle fatal error here

        cell.set(details: details[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
  .
  .
  .

  //Handle fatal error here
    cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row - 1])

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Crashes happen once your `posts` or `details` array is empty.

Modify you `cellForRow` function like this

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row == 0 && details.count > 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "detailscell") as! DetailsCellInHomeScreen
            if let imageURL = currentUserImageUrl {
                cell.configCell(userImgUrl: imageURL)
                cell.shareBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toCreatePost), for: .touchUpInside)
            }
            cell.set(details: details[indexPath.row])
            return cell
        } else if posts.count > (indexPath.row - 1) {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell

            cell.btnComment.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.btnComment.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toComments(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

            cell.favoritebutton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.favoritebutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(favupdate(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row - 1])
            return cell
        } else { 
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }
```

Comment: this solution is giving same error at "cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row - 1])
            "

Comment: Did you try to set a breakpoint to see how many elements in your `posts`?

Comment: yes I resolved the issue by "return posts.count" instead of "return 1 + posts.count"

Answer (score 0):

Take precaution and make conditional chekings as:

```
        if details.indices.contains(indexPath.row) {
            cell.set(details: details[indexPath.row])
        }
        if posts.indices.contains(indexPath.row - 1) {
            cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row - 1])
        }
```

It seems your arrays are not completed.